# HTTPS certificate error excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, certificate

Tried to look into the old questions, but couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that automatically scrapes the toner levels in our printers - however, there is a certificate error.

Instead of posting the website, IE (and therefore Excel/VBA) shows the cert.error HTML.

How can I bypass this? It is not possible to add the site to trusted sites - can VBA somehow ignore the error, or can I make VBA press tab, enter?
I've tried to use the following code, however no luck.

```
Enum readystate
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub ImportPrinterData()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate "https://to-port3-hp1c/"
    Do While ie.readystate <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.StatusBar = "Venter på printer data ..."
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set html = ie.document
    Application.SendKeys "{tab 7}", True
    Application.SendKeys "{return}", True
    MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML
    Set ie = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: my HP printer passes data in XHR   http://192.168.100.3/DevMgmt/ConsumableConfigDyn.xml    .... hit F12 key in chrome browser and examine "network" (F5 to refresh) .... then examine XHR files in "new tab"

Comment: @jsotola I don't get what you mean? Chrome is not an option, only IE.

Comment: navigate to your printer's web page using a browser on your computer. you can use IE or chrome. then you hit F12 (works in both) ..... go to "network" tab which shows you the interaction between the web browser and the web server (your printer in this instance)   .... some of the exchanges are XML files which are easier to parse.  ... each one has a unique URL ... if you printer does provide the XML data, then use the VBA code to read that

Comment: @jsotola I'll try that later today. But will it bypass the certificate error?

Comment: that i do not know, you can only try.